# How do you prop an exterior wall to replace rotted wood?

Tags: water, walls, exterior, rot

I have an exterior wall, so load bearing, that is damaged.  About a 6ft span.  It's damaged at the bottom at the foundation, but it is enough to replace the studs.

How do I prop up the roof on the exterior wall, so I can make the repair?  It is the stud, bottom plate, the whole thing.  I may be able to sister the stud, but I am not sure yet, as I have to remove more siding to get the whole picture.  Plus the wood is 50 years old, but that may be a good thing?

The home is one story, so I won't be propping up two floors or anything.  Edge of the roof at the exterior wall.

Comment: A picture will get you better answers.

Comment: 50 year old wood will have different dimensions compared to today's wood, at least 1/4 to 1/2 inch larger than new wood.

Comment: @crip659 Does that mean I have to replace all of it instead of a portion (sister)?

Comment: Just might need to add thin wood strapping to one edge so that it equals out.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without more detail. It would take a book to cover all the possible scenarios. Please revise to include photos or a sketch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be too difficult since according to your post, the top plate is OK. You'll need to get a few floor jacks and support the top plate from the foundation. You can rent them at most home stores. The jacks can be a little out of plumb to replace your bottom plate but then straighten them up. I would just replace all the studs. It will be quicker than messing around trying to sister them. Studs are cheap, you'll probably need 5.

Comment: The jacks can be that long?  That is about 8ft from bottom to top where the frame meets the roof.

Comment: They sure can. I see them all the time at construction sites and in home stores for rental.